# Resizing WebView with window

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, webview

I have a `NSView` that houses about a dozen `WebViews` populated with HTML generated from the application. When I first init them, I wait for `- (void)webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` to fire before laying them out and adding them to the view based on the `documentView` frame.

How would I go about resizing these `WebViews` along with the window? Is there a way to get the desired size of the `WebView` for a given width?

Comment: How are the views laid out? In a grid?

Comment: One below the other inside a scrollview. I'm using `WebViews` because I want to display MarkDown rendered text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all you're using the web views for is rendering MarkDown, you should instead investigate  [MacDown](https://github.com/sdegutis/Macdown) or [MarkdownLive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive). These render MarkDown directly into an `NSTextView`. This will be MUCH more efficient than multiple `WebView` objects.

In future, you should ensure that your question includes what you're actually trying to achieve because there's often a simpler way to do what you want than the way you think it perhaps should be achieved.